# mysql php preload selected in dropdown for loop

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have a for loop in a form which I need to have a pre-selected value from a mysql database. The for loop gives the options of 1-50, which is fine for a new input, but I want users to be able to re-open the form and edit values, so that when the form is opened to edit a record the already entered value is pre-selected in the dropdown.

This is my code

```
<?php

for ($i=1; $i<=50; $i++)
{
    ?>
        <option align="center" value="<?php echo $i;?>"><?php echo $i;?></option>

}
```

and the value I want to be pre-selected is stored in a variable. I found one answer that seemed to be what I wanted, but I couldn't make it work, probably because I am too much of a beginner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$saved_value = "value you get from db";
for ($i=1; $i<=50; $i++)
{
    ?>
        <option align="center" value="<?php echo $i;?>" <?php if($i == $saved_value) { echo "selected=selected"; } ?> ><?php echo $i;?></option>

}
```

You need to set "selected" property for that option

Comment: That seems to have worked perfectly, thank you very much indeed.